# How to read the contents of a file

Tags: perl

I am confused on how to read the contents of a text file. I'm able to read the files name but can't figure out how to get the contents. By the way the file is encrypted that's why I'm trying to decrypt.

```
#!/Strawberry/perl/bin/perl

use v5.14;

sub encode_decode {
    shift =~ tr/A-Za-z/Z-ZA-Yz-za-y/r;
}

my ($file1) = @ARGV;

open my $fh1, '<', $file1;

while (<$fh1>) {

    my $enc = encode_decode($file1);

    print my $dec = encode_decode($enc);

    # ... do something with $_ from $file1 ...
}

close $fh1;
```

Comment: You should check if `open` fails and report the error, i.e. add `... or die "Cannot open '$file1': $!"`. `$_` contains each line of the file you are reading, in line-by-line mode. As it happens, you can replace all that logic with `while (<>)`, which will automatically open files for you, or read from stdin as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
my $enc = encode_decode($file1)
```

passes the *name* of the file to `encode_decode`

A loop like `while ( <$fh1> ) { ... }` puts each line from the file into the default variable `$_`. You've written so yourself in your comment *“do something with `$_` from `$file1` ...”*. You probably want

```
my $enc = encode_decode($_)
```

And, by the way, your `encode_decode` subroutine won't reverse its own encoding. You've written what is effectively a ROT25 encoding, so you would have to apply `encode_decode` 26 times to get back to the original string

It's also worth noting that your shebang line

```
#!/Strawberry/perl/bin/perl
```

is pointless on Windows because the command shell doesn't process shebang lines. Perl itself will check the line for options like `-w` or `-i`, but you shouldn't be using those anyway. Just omit the line, or if you want to be able to run your program on Linux as well as Windows then use

```
#!/bin/env perl
```

which will cause a Linux shell to search the PATH variable for the first `perl` executable

Comment: Thanks for the help, now how do i get the a to line up with z when im decrypting. so hello encrypted would be gdkkn

Comment: @CorDell: Please ask a new question. Stack Overflow isn't a chat forum. You seem to have a assembled a formulaic program that uses bits of code that you have found elsewhere; I don't think you're truly understanding what you have written. I suggest you work through a Perl tutorial such as those recommended on [learn.perl.org](http://learn.perl.org/)

Comment: Ill admit it I used other peoples code, big deal? i know what it does and why else would it be out there? I'm not learning how to do this for anything its because i have too. And if I wana chat in my question then I can

Comment: @CorDell: You clearly *don't* know what it does, or you wouldn't have had to ask this question

Comment: @CorDell: And I'm saying that you should *learn Perl* sufficiently to know what the code your writing actually does, instead of cobbling together a Frankenstein's monster of a program and then rushing to others to ask us to fix what you have written